# How to detect by SP REST API whether it's SP online or SP on-premise server?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem

I know how to do it from [SPFX extension](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271762/how-to-detect-type-of-sp-server-in-spfx) but I need to detect SP type from desktop application interacting with SP by REST API.

Comment: Their Rest API host part are different, All SPO tenants are "xxx.sharepoint.com". Is it enough to detect the SP type?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. You can use `_spPageContextInfo.isSPO` to check if it is SharePoint online.

`_spPageContextInfo.isSPO` returns `true` if it is SharePoint online.

Refer below snapshot.

[image]

Comment: My app is C# desktop application, so I don't use SP JavaScript library and has no access to page context `_spPageContextInfo` object.

Comment: Do we have analog for "<site url>/_api/" request ?